# GPflow changepoint

Tags: python, gpflow

How to find changepoint locations using gpflow.kernels.changepoint. Post fitting a GPR model with this kernel, how to trace it back to actual changepoints in data? Code snippet/pseudo code or any sort of inputs will be much appreciated.
PS: I am trying to work this through on a financial time series data using Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gpflow.kernels.ChangePoints` kernel has a `kernels` attribute and a `locations` attribute. Lets say you are fitting a model of a ChangePoint between two kernels `[k1, k2]`. In that case, the `locations` attribute will contain the value of your predictor `x` at which the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) that is smoothly interpolating between the kernels `k1` and `k2` is centered. In addition, it may be of interest to look at the `steepness` parameter as well, which will tell you how steep the sigmoid is in addition to its location.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I tried to look for change points as you said, however, gpflow.kernels.ChangePoints need kernel and location as input, followed by optimisation to get optimised locations and corresponding steepness( with some other parameters). So, If I have understood correctly, we need to input location to get an optimised location, then how to identify the change points if it varies with each location also the same data segment. Correct me if I am going wrong here. Pseudo steps for locating change points would be really great.